# Confusion related to derivation of soft thresholding

Tags: convex-optimization

I was going through the derivation of soft threholding at http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22893361/papers/Soft%20Threshold%20Proof.pdf.

It says the three unique solutions for

$\operatorname{arg min} \|x-b\|_2^2  + \lambda\|x\|_1$ is given by

$\operatorname{arg min} \|x-b\|^2  + \lambda x$ assuming $x > 0$

$\operatorname{arg min} \|x-b\|^2  - \lambda x$ assuming $x < 0$

$\operatorname{arg min} \|x-b\|^2  = 0 $ assuming $x = 0$

I didn't get how it was derived. Any help?